# Conditional Execution of a Task in CICD pipeline Job not getting Executed

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-databricks, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the below main cicd-pipeline.yaml file which reads the latest files from our repo and prepares it to be deployed to our Dev workspace. I am using a Powershell task in the job to get the modified files from git for the current commit and then saving it to a temp location before proceeding to push it to the Build.ArtifactsStagingDirectory using the CopyFiles@2 task, before my DeployNotebooks stage could utilize those files from that location to be pushed to the databricks workspace. But I want this CopyFiles@2 task to be run only when the Powershell task is success and the flag inside it is set to True.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - 'main'

variables:
  - group: dbw-cicd-dev
  
  - name: vmImageName
    value: "windows-latest"
  - name: notebooksPath
    value: "notebooks"
  - name: notebooksFolder
    value: false

pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImageName)

stages:
  - stage: ChangedFolder
    displayName: "Checking the Notebooks folder changes"
    jobs:
      - job: preCheck
        displayName: "Copy_Notebooks"
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 2

          - powershell: |
              $files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
              $temp=$files -split ' '
              $count=$temp.Length
              echo "Total number of changed files: $count"
              For ($i=0; $i -lt $count; $i++)
              {
                $name=$temp[$i]
                echo "Changed file is: $name"
                if ($name -like 'notebooks/*')
                {
                  $flag = 'True'
                  echo "Is it a notebooks change: $flag"
                  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=notebooksFolder;isOutput=true]True"
                }
              }
              ##echo ${{variables.notebooksPath}}
              if (($flag -eq 'True'))
              {
                ## Now create a temp folder to hold the changed files
                New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\temp

                foreach($file in $temp)
                {
                  if(Test-Path -path $file)
                  {
                    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\temp
                    echo "File Moved: $file"
                  }
                }
              }              
            name: taskVariable

          - task: CopyFiles@2
            inputs:
              SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\temp'
              Contents: '*.py'
              TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/notebooks'
              CleanTargetFolder: true
            condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.notebooksFolder, True))

  - stage: DeployNotebooks
    displayName: "Deploy to DEV Environment"
    dependsOn: ChangedFolder
    condition: |
      and( 
        succeeded('ChangedFolder'),
        eq(dependencies.changedFolder.outputs['precheck.taskVariable.notebooksFolder'], 'True')
      )
    jobs:
      - job: Deploy_Notebooks
        steps:
          - template: templates/deploy-notebooks.yml
            parameters:              
              environmentName: $(dev-environment-name)
              resourceGroupName: $(dev-resource-group-name)
              serviceConnection: $(dev-service-connection-name)
              notebooksPath: $(notebooksPath)
```

But whenever the pipeline is run, this task is being skipped on evaluation.

[image: Azure DevOps Pipeline screenshot]

Could someone look into the condition block of CopyFiles@2 task and let me know what exactly am I missing here.

But when I change the condition to OR for the CopyFiles@2 task, it runs and errors out as below:

[image]

Comment: Btw, I changed the condition on CopyFiles@2 from AND to OR, but the pipeline throws error on sourcefolder as below:


##[error]Error: Not found SourceFolder: D:\a\1\s\temp
Finishing: CopyFiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the name of the task from where the variable should come. See this example:

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: setVariable
  displayName: "Set Variable"
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=notebooksFolder;isOutput=true]True"

- task: PowerShell@2
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['setVariable.notebooksFolder'], True))
  displayName: "Var condition"
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "notebooksFolder: $(setVariable.notebooksFolder)"
```

Note the name of the first powershell task is included in the condition of the second.

The example above will give you an output like this:
[image: output]

Comment: Thank you @GetShifting. it resolved my issue with the dependency condition which i was facing.

Comment: one more query. Now how do i use that copied files to be used in my next stage where i copy the notebooks to my databricks workspace. I have been using the Import-DatabricksFolder from the azure.databricks.cicd.tools powershell library. But its failing with the below error:
Set-Location : Cannot find path 'D:\a\1\notebooks' because it does not exist.
do you have any suggestion or resolution?

Comment: That would really depend on for example if you're using hosted or self-hosted agents. I would advice to create a separate question.

Comment: Thanks @GetShifting. I have sorted it out by myself, as it has to do with the hosted agents and managed to get it through using PublishBuildArtifacts and DownloadBuildArtifacts tasks. Thanks once again for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the last point of my question, where there is an issue of path not being recognized as the sourcefolder for CopyFiles task, I have switched that to PublishBuildArtifcats in my first stage and subsequently using the DownloAdBuildArtifacts task in my following stage to be used. Moreover, I had to identify whether its a self-hosted agent or not, and accordingly use the above two mentioned tasks and proceed accordingly.

[image]

Adding my final code changes as well, incase if someone has to refer for any similar issues [stages, jobs, tasks may vary according to the situation]

**cicd-pipeline.yml**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - 'main'

variables:
  - group: dbw-cicd-dev
  
  - name: vmImageName
    value: "windows-latest"
  - name: notebooksPath
    value: "notebooks"
  - name: notebooksFolder
    value: false

pool:
  vmImage: $(vmImageName)

stages:
  - stage: ChangedFolder
    displayName: "Checking the Notebooks folder changes"
    jobs:
      - job: preCheck
        displayName: "Copy Notebooks"
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 2

          - powershell: |
              $files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
              $temp=$files -split ' '
              $count=$temp.Length
              echo "Total number of changed files: $count"
              For ($i=0; $i -lt $count; $i++)
              {
                $name=$temp[$i]
                echo "Changed file is: $name"
                if ($name -like 'notebooks/*')
                {
                  $flag = 'True'
                  echo "Is it a notebooks change: $flag"
                  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=notebooksFolder;isOutput=true]True"
                }
              }
              ##echo ${{variables.notebooksPath}}
              if (($flag -eq 'True'))
              {
                ## Now create a temp folder to hold the changed files
                New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\temp

                foreach($file in $temp)
                {
                  if(Test-Path -path $file)
                  {
                    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\temp
                    echo "File Moved: $file"
                  }
                }
                ## zip the temp folder which only have the changed files
                Compress-Archive -Path $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\temp\* -DestinationPath $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\changedfiles.zip
              }              
            name: taskVariable

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              ArtifactName: 'MyNotebooks'
              publishLocation: 'Container'
            condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['taskVariable.notebooksFolder'], True))

  - stage: DeployNotebooks
    displayName: "Deploy to DEV Environment"
    dependsOn: ChangedFolder
    condition: |
      and( 
        succeeded('ChangedFolder'),
        eq(dependencies.changedFolder.outputs['precheck.taskVariable.notebooksFolder'], 'True')
      )
    jobs:
      - job: DeployNotebooks
        displayName: "Deploy Notebooks to DEV"
        steps:
          - template: templates/deploy-notebooks.yml
            parameters:              
              environmentName: $(dev-environment-name)
              resourceGroupName: $(dev-resource-group-name)
              serviceConnection: $(dev-service-connection-name)
              notebooksPath: $(notebooksPath)
```

Kindly note the **fetchDepth** variable in the above yml to be set to '2', as by default its set to 1 and no files are returned as part of the *git diff* command for the current commit.

**deploy-notebooks.yml**

```
parameters:
  - name: environmentName
    type: string
  - name: resourceGroupName
    type: string
  - name: serviceConnection
    type: string
  - name: notebooksPath
    type: string

steps:
  - checkout: self

  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Download Build Artifacts"
    inputs:
      artifactName: 'MyNotebooks'
      downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      CleanTargetFolder: true

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Unzip Build Artifacts" 
    inputs:
      pwsh: true
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        if(Test-Path -path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\notebooks)
        {
          Remove-Item -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\notebooks -Recurse -Force
        }
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\notebooks
        Expand-Archive -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\MyNotebooks\changedfiles.zip -DestinationPath $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\notebooks
    condition: succeeded()

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Deploy to Databricks Workspace"
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceConnection}}
      scriptType: "pscore"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt

        $databricksWorkspace = (az resource list --resource-group ${{parameters.resourceGroupName}} --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces']" | ConvertFrom-Json)[0]
        $databricksWorkspaceInfo = (az databricks workspace show --ids $databricksWorkspace.id | ConvertFrom-Json)

        $bearerToken = $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/CICD/scripts/DatabricksToken.ps1 -databricksWorkspaceResourceId $databricksWorkspaceInfo.id -databricksWorkspaceUrl $databricksWorkspaceInfo.workspaceUrl -databricksOrgId $databricksWorkspaceInfo.workspaceId

        Install-Module -Name azure.databricks.cicd.tools -Force -Scope CurrentUser
        Import-Module -Name azure.databricks.cicd.tools
        Import-DatabricksFolder -BearerToken $bearerToken -Region $databricksWorkspaceInfo.location -LocalPath $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\${{parameters.notebooksPath}} -DatabricksPath '/live'
```